# file_get_contents last record

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to make a small system to help me in my job. Reading some articles from here, testing and failing, I made this code work:

```
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true);
$opts = array( 'http'=>array( 'method'=>"GET",
          'header'=>"Accept-Language: pt-BR\r\n" .
           "Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSCSSRCRA=MHFGEDNDPHHBJDHGCMJKPDKN;    ASPSESSIONIDQCSTTDRB=EKJNDDNDGGFMAHBFJABMJNAM".session_name()."=".session_id()."\r\n" ) );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
session_write_close(); // unlock the file
$url = "http://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/mensagens_acomp.asp?prgcod=622924";
$contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
session_start(); // Lock the file

echo ($contents);

// Função para procura várias palavras em uma string
function procpalavras01 ($contents, $palavras, $resultado = 0) {
foreach ( $palavras as $key => $value ) {
$pos = stripos($contents, $value);
if ($pos !== false) {
$palavras_encontradas[] = $value; }
}
if (is_array($palavras_encontradas)) {
$palavras_encontradas = implode(",",$palavras_encontradas);
}
return $palavras_encontradas;
}

$palavras = array ("Ilma Chaves Pereira","19.026.964/0001-37","origina","correio","@");
$resultado = procpalavras01($contents, $palavras);

//Variáveis
$nome = ('ACLicita');
$mensagem = ('Pregoeiro chama no pregão');
$pregao = ('72016');
$uasg = ('160019');
$data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
$hora_envio = date('H:i:s');

// Compo E-mail
$arquivo = "
<style type='text/css'>
body {
margin:0px;
font-family:Verdane;
font-size:12px;
color: #666666;
}
a{
color: #666666;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #FF0000;
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<html>
<table width='510' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <tr>
          <td>
<tr>
             <td width='500'>Nome:$nome</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width='320'>Mensagem:$mensagem</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width='320'>Pregão:$pregao</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width='320'>Uasg:$uasg</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width='320'>Palavra Encontrada:$resultado</td>
            </tr>
        </td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>
        <td>Este e-mail foi enviado em <b>$data_envio</b> às <b>$hora_envio</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</html>
";
//enviar

// emails para quem será enviado o formulário
$emailenviar = "licitacoes.icp@gmail.com";
$destino = $emailenviar;
$assunto = "Atenção ao Pregão: " . $pregao . " Uasg: " . $uasg;

// É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: ACLicita';
//$headers .= "Bcc: $EmailPadrao\r\n";

if ($resultado === null) {
} else {
$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
}
```

It works fine, but I want this to check only the last message on the link (by date and hour), and if it is already sent don't send it again. The website has a refresh system, so my code refreshes every time the website refreshes, sending another mail if the words in $palavras are found. Help me or show me the way, some light how can I correct this. I don't know if I made myself clear.

Edit 1: Code trying to inserto into table:

```
if ($resultado === null) {
} else {
$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Licita (date, assunto, arquivo, email)
VALUES ('$date', '$assunto', '$arquivo', '$emailenviar')";
}
```

Comment: How can we tell if it has been send or not?

Comment: Thats the point i want to know too. As i told before i dont know anything about PHP. All i know is that the mail arrives if any word is found in the link.

Comment: You said "i want this to check only the last message on the link (by date and hour), and if it is already sent don't send again by mail", how can we tell if it has been send? Is there a specific word in the td's that says it has been sent?

Comment: Thanks for the help André, if you can see the link, in the message panel has date and time, if you open the link in browser and hit F12 u can see the this. I just dont know how to make the code check that date and hour. Is there a way to save the mail sent in a string to be checked later?

Comment: Yo need to maintain the records that which one is already sent. So that yoiu can compare with the sent and available.
While sending mail you can save to DB that you sent this one. And on next refresh you can check with you local Database whether you sent this on or not. Simple

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to store somewhere like in Database that which messages has been sent. See the comment below in you code.

```
//............................
if ($resultado === null) {
} else {
//get mail info from your local database (mysql) using current one
//if(you get null then send email otherwise you already have sent email)
$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
//save this mail info to DB 
}
//...............................
```

Actually to track which one you have sent you need to store each record after sending email. And before sending email you need to check with the DB that whether the new (last one) is exist in the DB or not.

 **Database:** Every time when you send the mail, please save that mail information to a local storage (file, database or any, MySQl recommended). And everytime when you send, before sending check whether the current record has been sent or not.

 **Session:** And if you just wanna check last one, then store that info into your session and don't let your session expire. So that you will have record of last one sent via email.

EDITED:

1. Insert Data into DB: [Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)
2. Read Data from DB: [Read](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: Thanks for replying Shailesh. Ill give a try, starting some mysql research as i dont know a point in DB.

Comment: Insert Data: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
Read Data: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Thanks again, trying to create a DB in PHPmyadmin, but need to read more about the types, collation, int and other needed stuff to create a DB.

Comment: for now just create a db table put id as int having size 11 , and for all other just put char having size 255 and for mail content just make that field as text. because you just started with DB so i think dont need to go much deeper just create table even with not optimized data types.

Comment: Hi, im trying to insert the data into the db, but no luck. I connect to db, but dont insert the values to the table.